# Where can I see the request data in an ASP.NET Core webservice?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, postman

I send 12345678 and cant find that in Visual Studio.

I am following this tutorial.
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

From POSTMAN, I send  "TemperatureCblah":"12345678", and want to see it in VStudio somehow. I know thats kinda primative, but walk/run I say.
[image]

In Visual Studio, I get to this breakpoint, but I cant find 12345678 anywhere....
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at HttpContext.Request.Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a model contains the field you want to accept from the json.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string TemperatureCblah { get; set; }
    public string sl { get; set; }
    public string tl { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it as parameter to receive the json data.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetAsync(TestModel testModel)
{
    //some code
}
```

Send Request from Postman:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your action is decorated with [HttpGet], it does not make sense to send a body in your (GET) request.

You can send values to a Get Action using query params, and you will be able to grab them using simple parameters like this:

`Get /weatherforecast?temperatureCblah=12345678`

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(string temperatureCblah)
{
    ...
}
```

For a POST request, then you can make an HttpPost decorated action and you may fill your request body that would be automatically parsed to an object model.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I used your code, but watch shows it as temperatureCblah= null